# Search a word using trim in macro

Tags: excel, macros, vba

Below is my code. I am searching each element from my array and filtering the data. After that, that element is searched in different sheet. I want that, if i am searching for "jump suit" in first case then it is filtering correct. But if that element is searched in second sheet then it displays error. Because in second sheet name is "jumpsuit". how to do make "jump suit" searchable as "jumpsuit"?

```
Dim Ar() As Variant
Ar() = Array("jump suit", "bikini")
Dim i As Variant
For Each i In Ar
Sheets("tops").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$1335").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & i & "*", Operator:=xlAnd
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1 > 0 Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells.Find(What:=i, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Sheets("tops").Select
    Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop While ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
Next i
```

Comment: You could use `newString = Replace(i, " ", "")` which will replace the space with nothing.

Comment: @TimWilkinson Superb!!!!!!! Thanks a lot bro

Comment: Posted as answer if anyone has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment you can use

```
newString = Replace(i, " ", "")
```

Which will replace the space with nothing.